# mysql_query return TRUE on empty table

Tags: php, mysql

> $rs = mysql_query("SELECT user, userid FROM House WHERE
>   userid='$userid'");

This return `Resource id #37`
The table House is empty, shouldn't it return FALSE?
According to the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

I have always gotten FALSE on error, but not this time.
Can someone explain, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is nothing wrong with your query, then `mysql_query()` will not return `false`. An empty result set is not an error.

Calling any of the fetch functions against that result *will* return `false`. `mysql_num_rows()` will return `0`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that. It's kinda weird that I have coded like this for so long without having problems.

Answer (score 4):

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() **returns a resource on success, or false on error**.

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc it returns trueon success or false on error.